# Function continues to return true even when it should be returning false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using NextJS and creating a client side form. I am trying to put validation in place client-side for the form and put those in a separate function, but every time I run the validateForm() function, it continues to return true regardless of input. I feel like I am missing something silly here but I am racking my brain and coming up with nothing. Below is the code

```
const [jobSubmission, setJobSubmission] = useState({});

   
    function handleChange (e){
        
            const jobInputName = e.target.name;
            const jobInputValue = e.target.value;
    
            const newJobSubmission = {
                ...jobSubmission, 
                [jobInputName]: jobInputValue,
            }

            console.log(newJobSubmission)
            setJobSubmission(newJobSubmission)
    }
    

    function validateForm (){
        console.log("Validation runnning")

        if(jobSubmission.jobCategory == `Please-Select` || jobSubmission.jobCategory === null){
            alert("Please make job category selection")
            return false
        }

        if (jobSubmission.salarRange !== null && jobSubmission.timeOfPayment === null){
            alert("Please select frequency of salary payment or remove salary range");
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

 

    function handleSubmission(){

        const isReady = validateForm()
        console.log(isReady)

        if (isReady === true){
        // Add UniqId
        const finalJobObject = {
            ...jobSubmission,
            jobId: uniqid()
        }

        sendJobToDB(finalJobObject)
        window.location = "/post-a-job/thank-you"
    } else{
        alert("Please fill in all required fields")
    }
        
    }
```

Basically I want to put validation checks in that separate validation function and have them actually return false when something is wrong.

I have tried changing how I track the boolean value, but it always returns true regardless

Comment: What have you done to debug this? What values are in `jobSubmission.jobCategory`, etc when it validates?

Comment: Looks like multiple things could be wrong here... doesn't look like anything is actually setting `jobCategory` or `salaryRange` into the state object (so when you check the properties strictly against `null` they actually come back as `undefined` and your function returns `true`) Also `salaryRange` is misspelled in your validation function

Comment: @MichaelAbeln You are correct across the board. It was everything you said, plus what Stephan mentioned about the mix of == and ===. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be due to the mix of `==` and `===` being used. I would try this first:

```js
function validateForm() {
    console.log("Validation running");

    if (jobSubmission.jobCategory === 'Please-Select' || jobSubmission.jobCategory === undefined) {
        alert("Please make a job category selection");
        return false;
    }

    if (jobSubmission.salaryRange !== null && jobSubmission.timeOfPayment === undefined) {
        alert("Please select the frequency of salary payment or remove the salary range");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

If you still have issues, I'd inspect the jobSubmission object in the console log and ensure that the values you're checking are as expected.

Comment: As simple as that! I think it was the combo of the mix of == and === as well as undefined vs null (as another commenter mentioned). Thanks for the help!